React native : Fold/Unfold - Dimensions api event listener is not working when app launches browser for login and then redirects after login success
I am Trying to detect fold unfold event using Dimensions change event listener as suggested in the documentation.
I have a initial landing page, when I perform fold/unfold, the event listener is called and my code is executed.
When I click on login , and my app redirects to okta and on successful login user is redirected to the app and home screen is displayed.
after the redirection and when the user is on Homescreen, when I try to fold/ Unfold the device, the dimensions event listener is not triggered.
It seems it is happening only when the redirection happens.
below is the code.
useEffect(() => {
const subscription = Dimensions.addEventListener('change',
    ({window, screen}) => {
    console.log('change detected'); //. this is not called after redirection happens
}); 
return () => {   
    subscription?.remove(); 
    };
}, []);

